# Why "object 'x' not found" on a line that does not use x?

Tags: r

I get this:

```
Error in paste0(width, on, k) : object 'x' not found
```

I'm utterly confused why it complains about 'x' on this particular line!

`on` is a character, `width` and `k` are numbers. `x` exists (it is a parameter of this function). That line and preceding ones look like:

```
print(index(x))
stopifnot(length(index(x))>=1)
#str(on);str(k);str(width)
extra=list( paste0(width,on,k) )
```

But what is even weirder when I added the commented out line *it* complains instead:

```
Error in str(on) : object 'x' not found
```

What triggered this question was a couple of call levels up I added this line:

```
rm(x)
```

(`rm(list=c("x"))` gives same behaviour.)

So, I *was* expecting an "x not found" error. But not at that line (not even in that function)!

**Background**: I found a bug where code was relying on a global variable called `x`, that should have been passed as a parameter. It worked in the unit test, failed in the real code, because the variable in question was not called 'x' in the real code!!  So, I decided to explicitly remove each variable when finished with it, to discover if I have any more bugs of this kind.

(If the above code snippets aren't enough for someone to go "Aha, Darren, you still don't get how R works do you...", I'll try and create a minimal example to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: odd behavior. I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: to avoid global variable side effect, try to use `local` and `xxapply  family functions` rather than `for`(if you use it of course)...

Comment: So, as `str(on)`throws an error, have you tried `paste0(width,k)`instead? If this goes smoothly, I think you should check, all assignments to `on`and see if you write something inside that you don't want to, and e.g. add a line cat(on) to the code.

Comment: You make us do too much guessing... Why not show us that whole function so we can reproduce the error and debug it?

Comment: It's physically impossible for `on` to be an object of class `character` and to get an error message in `str(on)` , AFAIK.  What is the actual value and class of `on`?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That was what I did `str` to try and find out :-).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone; it is helpful just to know other people think it shouldn't be happening, so I'll try and extract a minimal example from my hundreds of lines of real code, then will update the question.

Comment: Maybe `on` is/has a promise based on `x`, and that causes an error if you try to evaluate `on` when `x` no longer exists?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Now I understand it better, I see your guess was good: Primitive functions work just like promise objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was caused by `x` being used to make one of the parameters to the function call Here is a minimal example:

```
f=function(d,on){ print(on) } #AAA

x=1:4
attr(x,'extra')=list(a=1,b="xxx")
d=mean(x)

rm(x)   #Not needed any more

f(d, attr(x,'extra') )  # BBB
```

It gives the error for line #AAA (see below), instead of at #BBB, as you might expect.

This is because `attr` is a Primitive function. See http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Builtin-objects-and-special-forms

(And I finally found confirmation that Primitive functions work the same way as promise objects, i.e. delay execution: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#Argument-evaluation )

---

The error I get is as follows:

```
Error in print(on) : object 'x' not found
6: print(on) at dummy.R#1
5: f(d, (attr(x, "extra"))) at dummy.R#9
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(ei, envir)
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
1: source("dummy.R")
```

I.e. it complains about `x` not existing on line 1, not line 9. You can make function `f` much bigger, and not use `on` until much deeper in the function, even pass it to another function, and the error does trigger until `on` actually has to be evaluated. E.g. this longer example:

```
g=function(x,on){
    cat("Something else:",x,"\n")
    print(on)
}

f=function(d,on){
    cat("Do something:",d,"\n")
    g(d,on)
}

x=1:4
attr(x,'extra')=list(a=1,b="xxx")
d=mean(x)

rm(x)   #Not needed any more

f(d, (attr(x,'extra')) )
```

To spice up this example I've also added a parameter called `x` to `g()`. This mirrors the code in the original question, and it is easy to see how this can be confusing: "I have an x but it says it cannot see one!". To paraphrase Obi-Wan: "This is the not the `x` you're looking for..."

Comment: Can you explain what you're showing here?  I don't see `x` involved with `on` , and once you've calculated `d`, it doesn't care about `x` either. I ran your example and I get an error when executing #BBB line.  You can't get an error when simply defining a function AFAIK!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I expanded my answer. (BTW, I'm using R 3.0.1, on Ubuntu; if you're seeing different behaviour, I'd love to hear about it!)

Comment: OK, I understand what you did, but I don't see the problem.  You call `f` with argument `attr(x,'extra')` and you're surprised that an error isnt' thrown until something , i.e. `g` inside `f` tries to evaluate that argument?  That's the whole point of lazy evaluation.  I think you're mistaking the line numbers in your script with the order in which things happen when you execute `f(d,on)` . The fact that that is sourced from line 1 in your file is purely coincidental.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft No problem if you know that `attr`, and the other Primitive functions, work like a promise object :-)  For me the idea that a function as simple as `attr` would use lazy evaluation was completely unexpected.

Comment: Lazy evaluation is a general feature in R, check e.g. `f <- function(a, b=c) {c = a^2; a*b}` when you run e.g. `f(2)` it works well, although the second argument has a non-valid default, but it is defined in runtime.